# Fatal error: Call to a member function setsku() on a non-object in

Tags: php, sql-update

I've checked over 3 hours of related topic and I could't find the solution. 
  I try to update bulk SKUs in database, from a csv file.
  The code is:

```
 $updates_file="skus.csv";
$sku_entry=array();
$updates_handle=fopen($updates_file, 'r');

if($updates_handle) {
    while($sku_entry=fgetcsv($updates_handle, 1000, ",")) {
        $old_sku=$sku_entry[0];
        $new_sku=$sku_entry[1];
        echo "<br>Updating ".$old_sku." to ".$new_sku." - ";


        try {
            $get_item = $connect->query('SELECT catalog_product_entity FROM skirtbik_mage560->loadByAttribute("sku", $old_sku)');

            $get_item = 'SELECT sku FROM catalog_product_entity->loadByAttribute("sku", $old_sku)';
            $get_item23 = $connect->query('SELECT sku FROM catalog_product_entity');

            if ($get_item) {
                $get_item->setsku($new_sku)->save();

                echo $get_item;

                echo "successful";
            } else {
                echo "item not found";
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Cannot retrieve products from Magento: ".$e->getMessage()."<br>";
            return;
        }
    }
}
fclose($updates_handle);
```

The error is:

```
Updating ﻿10001 to 20001 - 
Fatal error: Call to a member function setsku() on a non-object in /home/skirtbik/public_html/magento/bulk_skus_update.php on line 25
```

Comment: `$get_item = 'SELECT sku FROM catalog_product_entity->loadByAttribute("sku", $old_sku)';` overwrites a variable.

Comment: Also, use `var_dump` instead of `echo` if you want to know the value of variables in trouble.

Comment: Trace your $get_item variable.  It is not what you think it is.

Comment: And we have perfectly no idea what your `$connect` variable is defined as.

Answer (score 0):

You are over writing and therefore destroying `$get_item` in these 2 lines

```
$get_item = $connect->query('SELECT catalog_product_entity FROM skirtbik_mage560->loadByAttribute("sku", $old_sku)');

// this line destroys the previous contents of $get_item
$get_item = 'SELECT sku FROM catalog_product_entity->loadByAttribute("sku", $old_sku)';
$get_item23 = $connect->query('SELECT sku FROM catalog_product_entity');
```

Use a different variable name for where you use `$get_item` the second time